# Issues with casting inconsistent dates with Apache Drill

Tags: sql, date, datetime, casting, apache-drill

I have list of dates which are unfortunately inconsistent:

```
3/09/2015 15:20:03
29/04/2014
06/03/2012
31/12/2015 06:29:40
13/05/2014
20/02/2010
01/10/2015 23:46:12
17/11/2014
30/10/2015 22:28:00
14/02/2014
```

I'm trying to cast these objects into a consistent format: date or timestamp but cannot do so with something like this:

```
 SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(DATE_OF_BIRTH, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss') FROM PERSON
```

or

```
 SELECT TO_DATE(DATE_OF_BIRTH, 'dd/MM/yyyy') FROM PERSON
```

The resulting error is shown.

```
UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalArgumentException: I nvalid format: "13/09/2015 15:20:03" is malformed at " 15:20:03" Fragment 0:0
```

How can I get drill to accept multiple formats for conversion.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the date, just cast the left-most 10 characters:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTR(DATE_OF_BIRTH, 1, 10), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
FROM PERSON
```